# Rewriting request to another site

Tags: multisite, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have a multisite WP instance set up to use subdirectories. I have a few pages that should have URLs on each site. The content will be (almost) the same, so I wanted to just make the pages once and rewrite requests to them from other sites. Allowing for future expansion, I thought I'd rewrite all pages that start with a given pattern ("foo-" in my example) to a common site. For example:

http://www.domain.com/dallas/foo-path

should rewrite to

http://www.domain.com/common-site/index.php?pagename=foo-path&market=dallas ,

and http://www.domain.com/el-paso/foo-path

should rewrite to

http://www.domain.com/common-site/index.php?pagename=foo-path&market=el-paso ,

but http://www.domain.com/dallas/bar-path

should rewrite to
http://www.domain.com/dallas/index.php?pagename=bar-path as usual.

Reading up on the problem, I don't think it's possible to rewrite the request to another site using add_rewrite_rule(), which is a shame, because I was trying to make a plugin to solve this problem. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Presuming it's not possible to do what I describe with add_rewrite_rule(), I'll have to modify .htaccess. It's currently at the default for WP subdirectory multisite; can anyone offer a suggestion on how to modify it to meet my goal?

**Update:** I tried adding the following condition and rule to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/common-site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?(foo-.+)$ common-site/$2?market=$1
```

When I look at the mod_rewrite log, it seems to be working:

```
rewrite 'dallas/foo-path/' -> 'common-site/foo-path/?market=dallas'
```

but I get a 404, even though foo-path exists on common-site.

Comment: I don't think this will work (could be wrong) but have you tried adding `[R=301,L]` to the end of your `RewriteRule`? In particular `L` instructs mod_rewrite that IF this rule matches then stop processing anything further rules after it. I.e. L = Last. Might be a case of the rule matching but then falling through to other rules, particularly the default WP rule hitting your `index.php` file and trying to then find `el-paso/foo-path` on the current site (being dallas) which `el-paso` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I tried adding `[L]` - no change. I don't want `R=301`, as I believe that does a redirect, not a rewrite, and I want this to appear like there is a page at the requested path.